# Reduction of order: $(t-1)y''-ty'+y=0$, $y_1(t)=t$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

This is a problem that's giving me a hard time:

Given that $y_1(t)=t$ is a solution to $(t-1)y''-ty'+y=0$, find a second independent solution using the reduction of order method (and solve an initial value problem that I won't specify here).

We know that a second independent solution is of the form $$y_2(t)=v(t)y_1(t)=v(t)t$$ for some function $v(t)$, so $$y_2'=v't+v\quad{}\text{and}\quad{}y_2''=v''t+2v'$$ Plugging in we get
$$(t-1)(v''t+2v')-t(v't+v)+vt=0$$
$$\implies v''(t^2-t)+v'(2t-2-t^2)=0$$

And letting w=v', $$\frac{w'}{w}=\frac{t^2-2t+2}{t(t-1)}=\frac{(t-1)^2+1}{t(t-1)}=\frac{t-1}{t}+\frac{1}{t(t-1)}=1-\frac{1}{t}+\frac{1}{t(t-1)}=1-\frac{1}{t-1}$$ where the last step is due to partial fraction decomposition of $\frac{1}{t(t-1)}$. So, integrating w.r.t to $t$ gives $$\int\frac{w'}{w}\;\text{d}t=\int1-\frac{1}{t(t-1)}\;\text{d}t$$ $$\implies\ln(w)=t-\ln(t-1)+c$$ $$\implies w=v'=c\frac{e^t}{(t-1)},\quad{}c\in\mathbb{R}$$ $$\implies v(t)=c\int\frac{e^t}{t-1}\;\text{d}t$$ which doesn't even seem like a standard function. Am I going wrong somewhere?

Comment: The second solution should be $e^{t}$.

Comment: Nicely spotted.

Comment: Make sure of your derivations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that there is a mistake $$\frac{w'}{w}=\frac{t^2-2t+2}{t(t-1)}=-\frac{2}{t}+\frac{1}{t-1}+1$$ so $$\log(w)=t+\log (t-1)-2 \log (t)+C$$ $$w=\frac{(t-1) }{t^2}e^{t+C}$$ and finally $$v=\frac{e^{t+C}}{t}=K\frac{e^{t}}{t}$$

Comment: Equivalently, you can write $v=\frac{\tilde{C}e^t}{t}$ where $e^C=\tilde{C}$.

Comment: Indeed and I should have done it ! I edit. Cheers :-)